Is it possible for a pseudoriemannian metric to induce a degenerate bilinear form?
Suppose we have a pseudoriemmanian manifold $(M,g)$ and a submanifold $N$. My question is simple: is it possible for $g|_{TN\times TN}$ to fail to be a pseudoriemannian metric by being degenerate? What if it were riemannian?

Yes, let $M$ be the vector space $\mathbb R^2$ with symmetric bilinear form $$(x_1,y_1;x_2,y_2) \mapsto x_1y_2 + x_2y_1.$$ Then the subspace spanned by $(1,0)$ is degenerate.
In the Riemannian (positive-definite) case, the answer is "no" as restricting a positive-definite symmetric bilinear form can only ever give you another positive definite form.

The (non)degeneracy of a bilinear form at a point depends only on the value at that point, so the question is mostly one of linear algebra:
Given a finite-dimensional vector space $\Bbb V$ endowed with a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form $g \in \operatorname{Sym}^2 \Bbb V^*$, is the restriction (pullback) of $g$ to a subspace $\Bbb W \subset \Bbb V$ necessarily nondegenerate?
The answer is no: If $g$ is not definite, there is a nonzero isotropic vector $v \in \Bbb V$ (i.e., a nonzero vector such that $g(v, v) = 0$). Then (denoting the inclusion by $\iota : \Bbb W \to \Bbb V$), the pullback $\iota^* g$ of $g$ to the $1$-dimensional span $\langle v \rangle$ of $v$ is the zero form.
More generally, if $g$ has signature $(p, q)$, then the kernel $$\ker \iota^* g := \{w \in \Bbb W : g(w, x) = 0 \textrm{ for all } x \in \Bbb W\}$$
can have any dimension between $0$ and $\operatorname{min}(p, q, \dim \Bbb W)$: To see this (assuming w.l.o.g. that $p \geq q$) it's convenient to work in a basis basis $(E_a)$ with respect to which the matrix representation of $g$ is
$$\pmatrix{\cdot & \cdot & I_q \\ \cdot & I_{p - q} & \cdot \\ I_q & \cdot & \cdot} .$$ Then, for example, $\langle E_1, \ldots, E_q \rangle$ is a maximal totally isotropic subspace.
In the particular case that the bilinear form $g$ is positive (resp. negative) definite: Every nonzero vector $w \in \Bbb W$ satisfies $g(w, w) > 0$ (resp. $< 0$), so $\iota^* g$ is definite and in particular nondegenerate).
The only complication introduced by passing to the manifold setting is that, when the signature of the bilinear form is indefinite, the signature (including the dimension of the kernel) of pulled-back bilinear form on the submanifold can vary from point to point. For example, for the bilinear form $g \in \operatorname{Sym}^2 T^* \Bbb R^2$ defined in standard coordinates by $g((x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)) := x_1 y_2 + x_2 y_1$, the pullback of $g$ to the unit circle $S^1 \subset \Bbb R^2$ has signature $(0, 1)$ at points in the first and third quadrants and signature $(1, 0)$ at points in the second and fourth quadrants, and is degenerate at the intersections of $S^1$ with the coordinate axes. For this reason, one often restricts attention to submanifolds on which the signature is the same at each point.

Here is a very simple example: Minkowski space $(M,g) = (\mathbb{R}^3, {\rm d}x^2+{\rm d}y^2-{\rm d}z^2)$, and $N = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon y=z\}$ a lightlike plane. If $\iota\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to N$ is the global parametrization given by $\iota(x,y) = (x,y,y)$, then the induced metric $\iota^*g = {\rm d}x^2$ is degenerate.
